# Where can I find the PackageID of my pre 7.0 Blackberry app?

Tags: blackberry

I'm having a boatload of trouble trying to submit my BB10 application, I managed to submit under a new product but it got rejected. So I have to add it as an upgrade to our existing <7.0 version. But it keeps telling me the PackageID needs to be the same.

I have no idea where to find the PackageID on my <7.0 app, I have the source code on my machine but not sure where to get the PackageID, any suggestions?

**EDIT: I get the following error message from Blackberry Vendor Portal (File Bundle upload section):**

File bundle (my_app-2_0_0_1.bar) has been rejected. Package ID is required for all .bar file. If this is an upgrade, Package ID must match Package ID in original file bundle.

Comment: I'm missing something here.  I have just reviewed an app that has both BB7 and BB10 variations on BB World, and I'm not sure what you mean by the PackageID.  Which screen is asking for this?

Comment: Hi Peter! The vendor portal screen where I add my File Bundle is where my error is displayed. I will update my question.